# Loosely coupled movement

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I'm working on my ability to write loosely coupled applications that follow SOLID principles. This is a simple application trying to demonstrate the concept. Is it OK? Am I going along the right lines? What needs to be improved or changed?

I'd just like your overall opinion on the design structure and the code please. If you'd like a straightforward question to answer directly, then it'd be "Is this code that is appropriate to be used in production?"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LooselyCoupled
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Usage
        Human human = new Human();
        human.Name = "John";
        human.Age = 36;

        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.Name = "Molly";
        cat.Age = 8;

        MovementManager movement = new MovementManager(human);
        movement.Move();

        MovementManager movement2 = new MovementManager(cat);
        movement2.Move();
    }

    //Interface to act as a middle man (inversion) to redirect the otherwise narrow flow
    public interface iMovement
    {
        void Move();
    }

    //A manager that has no idea of any implementation, but only an interface
    public class MovementManager
    {
        private iMovement movement;

        public MovementManager(iMovement movement)
        {
            this.movement = movement;
        }

        public void Move()
        {
            movement.Move();
        }
    }

    //I've decided that every class that implements iMovement will have certain attributes
    //therefore I've decided to add an abstract class into the mix (is this OK?)
    public abstract class BaseMovementEntity : iMovement
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public abstract void Move();
    }

    public class Human : BaseMovementEntity
    {
        public override void Move()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {Name}, Age {Age} has begun moving...");
        }
    }
    public class Cat : BaseMovementEntity
    {
        public override void Move()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The little cat whose name is: {Name}, Age {Age} has begun moving to catch the dog...");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me share my thoughts. From the SOLID perspective your example is very simple and does not explicitly break any principles.

The only thing that you should not do in large-scale production code is to couple your application code (`MovementManager`, etc.) with execution host (Console app project).

What you should usually do is to put your application code into separate assembly(ies), employ some [DI Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) and create a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) (also preferable in separate assembly). Application code/assemblies must not have any references to DI Container or Composition Root. On the other side, your execution host (Console App project) must reference Composition Root and Application Code assemblies, and resolve an instance of `MovementManagerFactory` via DI Container. Then you can use `MovementManagerFactory` to create your `MovementManager` with appropriate `iMovement` object.

You would need `MovementManagerFactory` because your `MovementManager` constructor requires `iMovement` object. To simplify things I'd rather remove that constructor and instead pass `iMovement` object to the `Move()` method directly:

```
public class MovementManager
{
    public void Move(iMovement movement)
    {
        movement.Move();
    }
}
```

As a side note: everywhere in your application when you use `new` operator to create an instance of a class, you potentially make your code tightly coupled. It is especially true when that 'new-ed' class belongs to another module or component.

Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann is an excellent book about design of loosely coupled application.

Comment: *does not explicitly break any principles.* Yes it does. Encapsulation. Pass `Human` values thru a constructor instead of setting them directly.  Worst case, client code will end up rife with redundancy  ensuring `Human` objects are OK to use. `Human` objects become dependent on clients for internal state and its functionality therefore "leaks" and ends up everywhere except in the `Human` class.

Comment: Given the leaky encapsulation (comment above) the DI container and separate assemblies will be super-glue coupled if they use the `Human` class. `Human` API is incoherent - state is indeterminate because `Human` does not have responsibility for its state.

Comment: Thanks @radarbob, that's true, but it alway depends on your use cases and you first need to define what is consistent or inconsistent state for the Human object. Since the question doesn't specify that and was about SOLID principles, my answer was about SOLID only.

Comment: *when you use new operator to create an instance of a class, you potentially make your code tightly coupled.* Well designed classes naturally, intentionally result in a web of coupling. So "potentially" is wrong, and "tightly" implies something bad. But  *undesirable* coupling is minimized by dependency injection. Using method/constructor parameters is by far the most common way of DI. Note the `Human` class (comments above) does not have DI.

Comment: *you first need to define what is consistent or inconsistent state for the Human object*. I agree, it is not defined in the OP. Constructor parameters do that. This is why "constructor" is a thing distinct from mere methods.

Comment: *... loosely coupled applications that follow **S**OLID principles*. `Human` violates **S**ingle responsibility due to the leaky encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks @radarbob, I think John who asked the question would appreciate if you compile your ideas in a separate answer rather that commenting all other answers. That would be more constructive approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few more things I'd like to add to the very good points mentioned by @[Jk_xp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/147370/59161).

- You use nested classes. This should be avoided because it makes finding and using class harder. For grouping you should use namespaces.
- We use PascalCase for all public types and members in C# so it should be `IMovement`.
- Usually if possible it's better to choose and adjective for the interface name. Here the name `IMoveable` would be more appropriate.
- You don't have to call each type derived from `IMoveable` - `MovementSomething`, an interface is usually a *capability* so I'd pick the name `Animal` for the base type in your example. This shows more clearly that it's an abstraction with a certain ability.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, I would like to point out an old design issue. Which is: inheritance does not work that well, when it comes to programming *behaviors*. It is somewhat ok for small applications, but it scales poorly. For example, your  `BaseMovementEntity` class is not going to cut it, if you add an entity that is "movable", but does not have a name or age. You'd have to implement another base class, without those properties. This can quickly turn into really complex hierarchies, as the number of behaviors and entities grows. That is why applications, that heavily rely on entities and behaviors (most modern games, for example), normally use composition instead of inheritance. So you d have something like:

```
var human = new Actor();
human.AddBehavior(new HumanoidWalk());
var cat = new Actor();
cat.AddBehavior(new CatWalk());
```

You can read more on the issue, for example, [here](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/).

Comment: I agree only because defining the class declares`abstract Move()` then implements `IMovable.Move()` and then does not declare any `IMoveable` references.  I infer from this answer that having both the abstract class method and interface doesn't make sense. The interface is not needed because subclasses are already guaranteed to implement `Move()`. Keyword `interface` interfaces are for giving common behavior to otherwise unrelated classes. All `BaseEntity` subclasses are related; the interface is mis-used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers pretty much cover most of what I wanted to say, but I'd still like to point out a couple things.

1. As touched on by @NikitaB, Age and Name are separate concepts to Move, so the `BaseMovementEntity` class either shouldn't implement them (in which case the class shouldn't exist at all), or should be renamed to something less movement-specific (e.g. a higher level concept of something which has an age and name, and the ability to move).
2. I don't like the name `IMovement` as an interface. You don't `Move` a *movement*, you move something that is *movable*. So I would rename it to `IMovable`.
3. I don't see the point of `MovementManager` in its current incarnation. It takes a single object and calls a method on it, when it would make more sense to call it on the object directly. `human.Move()` vs `movementManager.Move()` (is the manager moving?). Specifically, in your `Main` function it would make more sense to see:

.

```
BaseMovementEntity human = new Human(); // because you appear to be interested in using abstractions.
BaseMovementEntity cat = new Cat();
// ...set properties...
human.Move();
cat.Move();
```

Now let's say you don't want to be moving these objects directly, you want some "manager" object that does it for you. In that case you (a) don't need a manager per movable object, and (b) don't need it to take a `BaseMovementEntity` object (which has other properties accessible unrelated to the ability to move). So effectively what you'd want is a manager class like the example that @jk_xp showed, where you pass the movable object to the manager's `Move()` method.

Comment: Ditto emphasis on #3. The OP has already implemented the strategy pattern by providing `abstract Move()`. Classic and appropriate polymorphism for `Move`.  `MovementManager` would be good if it was implementing herding behavior. It is an SRP violation to have individual animal objects control each others movement.